# SQL Server Date Casting Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

On my install of SQL Server if I perform the following

```
SELECT CAST('2008-05-03 00:00:00' AS DATETIME), CAST('2008-05-03T00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

Then I get the following result

```
2008-03-05 00:00:00.000 2008-05-03 00:00:00.000
```

Now this is odd in itself as I'm not sure why it's parsing the first date as yyyy/dd/mm (my login is set to british english btw) and that date format is not a standard one AFAIK.

I'm not sure where to start poking to try to resolve this odd parse issue which doesn't seem to occur ion any of my colleagues systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first format is indeed a language-dependent format (ODBC canonical), and since your system is defined to be "British English", it will be interpreted as `YYYY-DD-MM` (if it's "American English", it would be interpreted as `YYYY-MM-DD`).

However, the second one is the [ISO-8601 standard date format](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) that will work on any installation of SQL Server, regardless of your language or locale settings. It's format is **always** `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` and will be interpreted as such.

Try this:

```
SET LANGUAGE british

SELECT 
    CAST('2008-05-03 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) 'UK Date',
    CAST('2008-05-03T00:00:00' AS DATETIME) 'UK ISO Date'

SET LANGUAGE  us_english

SELECT 
    CAST('2008-05-03 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) 'US Date',
    CAST('2008-05-03T00:00:00' AS DATETIME) 'US ISO Date'
```

My output is:

```
UK Date                    UK ISO Date
2008-03-05 00:00:00.000    2008-05-03 00:00:00.000

US Date                    US ISO Date
2008-05-03 00:00:00.000    2008-05-03 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: It's interesting because the first one, '2008-05-03 00:00:00', is interpreted as yyyy-mm-dd on every other db in our enterprise (50+) rather than the yyyy-dd-mm which my server seems to do.

Comment: @Chris Meek: boy, those date conversions really get messy at times! Updated my answer with the hopefully correct statement now....

Comment: @Chris What's the server's date format set to? Bear in mind SQL Server defaults to US format out-of-the-box, even when installing on a British English server...

Comment: Cool, thanks for that.  In defence of us brits, we'd never use yyyy-dd-mm as a date format!

Comment: @Matt the server is US English, the user is set to British English

Answer (score 1):

Can you use convert instead?  This will allow you to specify the date format which I'm not sure you can do using cast:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2008-05-03 00:00:00', 120), CONVERT(DATETIME, '2008-05-03T00:00:00', 126)
```

You can take a look at the various formats here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is using the collate configuration as in your session. You can avoid ambiguity **setting the date format in line**:

```
SET dateformat dmy
SELECT CAST('2008-05-03 00:00:00' AS DATETIME), CAST('2008-05-03T00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
-- 2008-03-05 00:00:00.000 2008-05-03 00:00:00.000

SET dateformat mdy
SELECT CAST('2008-05-03 00:00:00' AS DATETIME), CAST('2008-05-03T00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
-- 2008-05-03 00:00:00.000 2008-05-03 00:00:00.000
```